# Can we alter/engineer natural "constants"?

Tags: physical-constants

There are numerous constants that define the physical universe, from the fine structure constant to Planck to the speed of light etc.

Can any of these be altered locally? For example, it seems that we might be able to [alter the speed of light in vacuum using the Casimir Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scharnhorst_effect) Are there any other possible examples?

Comment: I suppose constants could be promoted to fields, which could evolve, and we could influence that evolution.

Comment: But a constant isn't dynamical by definition, so no we cannot alter them.

Comment: I'm rather looking for an experimental approach as I outlined above

Comment: @innisfree That's why I put "constants" in inverted commas. However, even Dirac talking about varying constants so I don't think I am in bad company https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis

Comment: Vernor Vinge in "A Fire Upon the Deep"  creates a universe in which certain physical laws (affecting FTL travel) vary with distance from galactic clusters.   You're not going to be able to do any of this in our universe.

Comment: The Casimir effect doesn't alter the speed of light in vacuum any more than a simple waveguide does. The speed of light in vacuum is the speed of light in vacuum, it's not the speed of light in some sort of enclosed volume. Of course the latter is different... one does not need to go to quantum mechanics to know that. The classical theory predicts it, already.

Comment: @CuriousOne Scharnhorst effect

Comment: Exactly... two plates is not the same as vacuum. That's as trivial as it sounds.

Comment: @CuriousOne Except that it is faster than c in vacuum, and we are not talking about phase velocity etc but "real" speed. It is not predicted in classical physics

Comment: Predictions in physics have only one use: to invalidate hypotheses. If this is a firm prediction of QFT and no such effect can be found in nature (and so far it has not been), then this would invalidate QFT. I am more inclined to believe, though, that it's just a poorly interpreted calculation. Irrespective of that... it's still not an effect that changes the speed of light in vacuum.